# How to display table on hover using only css?

Tags: html, css, hover

Is it possible to display a table on hover with data using only css?

Like when you hover your mouse on your cart on Amazon the items in your cart display:

[image]

Is it better practice using a script than css?

The cart widget:

```
<a href="viewCart"><fmt:message key='cart'/> 
<img style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" alt="" src="images/cart-icon.png" align="top" vspace="8"> (${cart.numberOfItems})</a>
```

The header CSS:

```
#headers {
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom-color: #f8f8f8;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #333333;
    margin-top: -4px;
    border-bottom-width: 0.1em;
    color: #eaeaea;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: small;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    font-weight: bolder;
    z-index: 10;
    max-height: 40px;
    line-height: 200%;
}

#logo_container {
    border-style: solid none none;
    border-top: 0.2em solid #cccccc;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 50px;
    font-size: small;
    text-align: right;
    height: 50px;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: PRINT CLEARLY;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 10;
    font-style: normal;
    background-color: #333333;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    color: #666666;
    font-weight: bold;
}

    <%--Cart Widget--%>
    <a href="viewCart" id="ShowCart"><fmt:message key='cart'/> 
        <img style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" alt="" src="images/cart-icon.png" align="top" vspace="8"> (${cart.numberOfItems})</a>

        <table id="minicart">
    <tr>
        <td>img</td>
        <td>name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>img</td>
        <td>name</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><a href="viewCart">View Cart (${cart.numberOfItems})</a></td>
    </tr>

</table>



</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: plz share your HTML & CSS please

Comment: Since you want solution using css, remove javascript and jquery tag

Comment: @Satpal: Well actually what would be the best practice? CSS or Scripts?

Comment: I'm sure the best solution is javascript.  css hover is only for changing some css rule, But you want to add a DOM element inside your page. You can easily do this via javascript or jquery.

Comment: @hamed: something like `$('#cart > .heading').bind('mouseover', function() {`?

Answer (score 2):

there are some ways of implementing that using css, see demo 
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/KlipJan/8nups60o/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="viewCart" id="ShowCart">show cart</a>
<table id="cart">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">My Cart</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>$300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>$700</td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
#cart{
display:none;
}
#ShowCart:hover + #cart{
display:block;
}
```

WITH THE ORIGINAL CODE:

```
    <style type="text/css">

    #minicart{
        display:none;
    }
    #ShowCart:hover + #minicart{
        display:block;
    }

    </style>


<a href="viewCart" id="ShowCart"><fmt:message key='cart'/> 
        <img style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" alt="" src="images/cart-icon.png" align="top" vspace="8"> (${cart.numberOfItems})</a>

        <table id="minicart">
    <tr>
        <td>img</td>
        <td>name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>img</td>
        <td>name</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><a href="viewCart">View Cart (${cart.numberOfItems})</a></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Your code works great by its own but for some reason, when I integrate it with the original code, the css hover effect doesn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

CSS *:hover* is suitable for adding css rule to element on hover. For example if you have something like `p:hover {color: red}`, browsers change `p` color to red on hover. But if you want to change DOM structure(like add an element, remove an element, ...) on hover, it's better to use jquery. 
You can do this:

```
$("#cart > .heading").hover(function(){
   //function for adding div under cart goes here
}, function(){
   //function for removing div goes here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hover(function(){
          $('table').css({'display':'block'});
        },function(){
         $('table').css({'display':'none'});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Cart.</p>
<table style='display:none' >
<tr>
<th>heading</th></tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I think it may helps you.

Comment: Tried your code: 

`<%--Cart Widget--%>
    <p><a href="viewCart"><fmt:message key='cart'/> 
            <img style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" alt="" src="images/cart-icon.png" align="top" vspace="8"> (${cart.numberOfItems})</a></p>

   <table style='display:none' >
<tr>
<th>heading</th></tr>

</table>`

Comment: It made my cart totally disappear.. :/

Comment: Can you explain me what exactly your looking for ? whats are the changes you needed ?